# Overriding TCA values in pageTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-tca

I want to change the label of **tt_address** records when displayed in the list view. Instead of *"name"* there should be used the value of the field *"organization"* as the default label. I'd like to achieve this by overriding the **TCA** -if possible- via TypoScript in the **pageTS**. Unfortunately the following attempt did not have the desired effect:

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_address {
        ctrl {
            label = company
            label_alt = name, last_name, first_name
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `TCEFORM`, I tried it with `TCADefaults`, but that did not change anything.
What would be the right definition to reach that goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the displayed columns in list module you have to overrides TCA in your own extension. In file EXT:xyz/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['label'] = 'company';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['label_alt'] = 'name, last_name, first_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the column name to overwrite the label. Form is `TCEFORM.[tableName].[fieldName].[propertyName]`

In your case you want to overwrite field 'name'.

```
TCEFORM.tt_address.name.label = Company
```

See for further details: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you got me wrong. I don´t want to change any label of the edit form. What I try to achieve is to change the labels in the list view of tt_address records.

Comment: Sorry. Create a file typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php. There try `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['label'] = 'company';`and 
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['label_alt'] = 'name, last_name, first_name';`

Comment: So there´s no way to manipulate the TCA via TypoScript? Too bad, would be cool to apply those changes to specific entry points of the pagetree.
Thanks for the hint regarding AdditionalConfiguration, wasn't aware of this possibility. Unfortunately this has no effect in this case. After flushing the cache I looked up the configuration in the backend and there are still the initial values for `label`and `label_alt`.

Comment: I test it by myself and you are right. But in a extension it works. In file EXT:xyz/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php add this line
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_address']['ctrl']['label'] = 'company';`

Comment: I got the problem under control as follows: I changed the (traditional TYPO3) site to a sitepackage extension and manipulated the TCA using the tt_content.php file, as recommended by you. Thanks @Heinz, You gave me the crucial tip!

Comment: OK. I made a new answer you can accept as solution, please.